# Castle windsor resolve instance in custom code

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

How can I leverage Windsor's lifestyle management but have my own resolve method?
At the moment I register my dependency as follows:

```
_container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>()
    .ImplementedBy<EntityContext>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionName", "EntityContext"))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

I would like to resolve the dependency by following lambda:

```
() => {
    return new EntityContext("EntityContext");
}
```

How can this be combined?

Comment: `return _container.Resolve<DbContext>();`

Comment: I am not sure I described my question well. But I would like this code `return _container.Resolve<DbContext>();` to call my lambda method.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`UsingFactoryMethod`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#using-a-delegate-as-component-factory) to specify how to create the instance:

```
container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new EntityContext("EntityContext"))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```